# Force border crossing point using Here Api

Tags: here-api

I'm interested if there is a way to specify border crossing point for cross border routes?

For example, I'm setting start in Monterrey, Mexico, finish in LA, CA and I want route over Tijuana, Mexico. What I get is route over Laredo, TX and then when in San Diego, route goes to Tijuana, back to San Diego and then to LA. So instead of 1 border crossing I have 3 now.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Parameter **region** can be specified to include cross countries in fleet telematics API for more precision. However by default, this will cover the entire world coverage. Please find the link below as reference documentation :

> developer.here.com/documentation/fleet-telematics/api-reference.html#tag%2FRouting-&-Route-Matching%252Fpaths%252F~12~1calculateroute.json%252Fget